# What does temperature refer to in the vacuum of space?

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology, temperature, universe, cosmic-microwave-background

If light was released ~.38MY after the big bang and the expansion of the universe has caused it to shift into the microwave region why is it referred to as being 2.7K? Temperature is the movement of excited molecules in a medium whereas radiation only has frequency and intensity. What does the "temperature" mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Temperature in space](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/51692/)

Comment: See also [The temperature in space is about 3K, however there are almost no atoms in space. How can there be residual heat?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/213123/)

Comment: Also [How can interstellar space have a temperature of 2-3K?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/133985/)

Comment: @john rennie ok